# JDK version mismatch problem，Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteOutputStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I imported a third-party package that used jdk8, but my project used jdk11, and then reported an error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

`com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/util/ByteOutputStream   at com.sm.huichuan.api.sdk.core.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:61) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.getAccount(Unknown Source) at com.example.work1.utils.AccountServiceExampleTest.testGetAccount(AccountServiceExampleTest.java:20) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:177) at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:142) at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122) at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142) at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125) at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:130) at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:241) at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:236) at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteOutputStream at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ... 23 more`

I found that jdk11 removed some classes, I imported some dependencies, but still reported an error, but I can not find the answer, please help!

```
<dependency>  

 <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>

   <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId> 

  <version>3.0.0</version> 

</dependency>
```

Comment: If a library uses undocumented, internal JDK classes that were removed from later Java versions, the only options are really to update the library to avoid using those classes or stay on a JDK version that supports them.

Comment: All right......